# Bootstrap package not working in Meteor

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I added twbs:bootstrap to my packages file to download it.  I went to the docs for that package and it led me straight to the Bootstrap web sight. Then tried inserting the following code from that web-sight for a header

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active">
<a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">...</a></li>
<li><a href="#">...</a></li>
</ul>
```

But it just gives me an unordered list not in the form of a navbar.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to open the bootstap documentation and to paste some navbar code. It should work. Just see the example and try to modify it. According to your preferences.

Comment: That's where I got the code from.  The docs for the package just led me to get getbootstrap web-sight.

Comment: try to add the <nav> tags

Comment: Tried that too but didn't work.  Could you show me exactly how you would do it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found the solution.  Wherever you have "class=", use instead "className=".

See https://gist.github.com/zpao/6321691 and  https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/328 for the decision to invalidate "class" in favor of "className".  That was over two years ago -- you'd think they would have updated the documentation to match

Answer (score 0):

This is the navbar of one of my apps. Use this as an example and change according to you preferences:

```
      <div class="container-fluid navbar-inner">
           <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Some Brand</a>
           </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a>{{>loginButtons}} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Somewhere</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Somewhere</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Somewhere</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->


      </div><!-- / container-fluid -->

</nav>
```